# PRISM WPF CompositeCommand Execute method not working

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I have a moduleA which needs to execute a code in moduleB's ViewModel. So I created a commandProxy in my infrastructure and registered a command in moduleB. When I called the Execute on the proxyCommand, the registered command wont execute. How should i go about the debugging?

ModuleA

```
commandProxy.ShowOrderCommand.Execute(""); // I can see the registered command in the debugger
//This is obtained through constructor injection
```

ModuleB

```
showOrderDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => { }, SubmitAllCanExecute);
commandProxy.ShowOrderCommand.RegisterCommand(showOrderDetailsCommand);

private void ShowOrderDetailsView()
        {
            _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.SecondaryRegion, new Uri("/TradeLogView", UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

Infrastructure

```
private static CompositeCommand showOrderDetailsCommand = new CompositeCommand(true);

public class PostMatchCommandProxy
    {
        virtual public CompositeCommand ShowOrderCommand
        {
            get { return ShowOrderDetailsCommand; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of command, can't you use `EventAggregators`. You can do subscribe to an event in module B and publish the event whenever required from module A. This is much easier approach than having commands in place.

Answer (score 1):

I missed the function definition in the delegate command

showOrderDetailsCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowOrderDetailsView, SubmitAllCanExecute);